# SpriteKit - Collision Off after HIT

Tags: sprite-kit, game-engine

I am writing a spritekit game and I have a problem, I would like the framework not to detect collisions after it is detected. For example, the player is dealt damage and becomes insensitive to attacks, e.g. for 20 seconds. Now when a collision is detected, it is detected all the time (e.g. 50 times)

Is there a way to temporarily disable collisions ??

Player code : 
func createPlayer() {

```
    var walkFrames: [SKTexture] = []
    var walkFrames2: [SKTexture] = []
    var walkFrames3: [SKTexture] = []
    var walkFrames4: [SKTexture] = []


   // let spaceShipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "p2.png")
    let playerAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walk")
    let playerAnimatedAtlas_idle = SKTextureAtlas(named: "idle")
    let playerAnimatedAtlas_jump = SKTextureAtlas(named: "jump")
    let playerAnimatedAtlas_attack = SKTextureAtlas(named: "attack")
    var _: [SKTexture] = []


    for i in 0...6 {
      let playerTextureName = "1_entity_000_WALK_00\(i).png"
      walkFrames.append(playerAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(playerTextureName))
    }

    for z in 0...6 {
      let playerTextureName_idle = "1_entity_000_IDLE_00\(z).png"
      walkFrames2.append(playerAnimatedAtlas_idle.textureNamed(playerTextureName_idle))
    }

    for p in 0...6 {
      let playerTextureName_jump = "1_entity_000_JUMP_00\(p).png"
      walkFrames3.append(playerAnimatedAtlas_jump.textureNamed(playerTextureName_jump))
    }
    for k in 0...6 {
      let playerTextureName_attack = "1_entity_000_ATTACK_00\(k).png"
walkFrames4.append(playerAnimatedAtlas_attack.textureNamed(playerTextureName_attack))
    }

    playerWalkingFrames = walkFrames
    let firstFrameTexture = playerWalkingFrames[0]

       player.position = CGPoint(x: -1050, y: -90 )

    //player.setScale(0.090)
    player.size = CGSize(width: 170, height: 120)
   // player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width: 35, height: 100))
    let spaceShipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "p2.png")
    let texturedSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spaceShipTexture , size: CGSize(width: player.size.width,
                                                                                height: player.size.height));
    player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    //player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: play, size: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation =  false
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemy1Category
    //player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemy1Category

    playerWalkingFrames_idle = walkFrames2
    playerWalkingFrames_jump = walkFrames3
    playerWalkingFrames_attack = walkFrames4






    self.addChild(player)
}
```

collision code :

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let collison: UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

```
    if collison == playerCategory | enemy1Category{
        print("COLLISION") }

        else {
            //print("Brak Kolizji" )
        }
    if collison == playermieczCategory | enemy1Category {
        print("miecz")

    }

    if collison == playermieczCategory | piratkaCategory {
        print("miecz_Piratka")
      //  health -= 0.2
     //   piratka.isHidden = true


        }
    if collison == playerCategory | piratkaCategory{
    // if collison == nil {return}
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
     //   czarny.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 0))


   //     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)) {
   //         self.playerhealth -= 0.01
  //          print("nico")
            print("HIT3")

     //   }

        }
```

Comment: could you provide the code you've working on so far? Please consider to take a look at [example]

Comment: Yes , i just edit

Comment: Couple ways you can do this. Use the current time and check if X seconds have passed or use frames per second with a counter.

Comment: One simple approach can be a Timer/SKAction and modify a flag to control the hits. One more complex approach but more scalable is to make a state machine (GameplayKit) with player statuses and do not make anything when it is invulnerable. Or make components like powerups (GameplayKit) to make invulnerable in some situations like Mario Bros.